# Oracle 12c datapump error when exporting from 11g database

Tags: oracle11g, oracle12c, datapump

I am using the following in cmd.

```
expdp system/*****@11.11.1.11:1521/orcl schemas=HR directory=DATADIR
dumpfile=HR_20150625.dmp logfile=HR_20150625.log version=11.2
```

- The database from which schema is to be exported is 11g (11.2.0.1.0)
- The datapump utility is of 12c (12.1.0.1.0)

I get following error

```
UDE-00018: Data Pump client is incompatible with database version 11.2.0.1.0
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: That error makes it seem like you are doing it the other way around... You are receiving the `UDE` error on the 12c database?

Comment: Affirmative. The schema is in a Oracle 11g database on Server A. The Server B has Oracle 12c. Now I am running expdp in Server B to export schema in Server A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to My Oracle Support Note 553337.1 you'll need an 11.2 expdp client to do the export from an 11.2 source database. Cf. this matrix:

```
Export Data   Connecting to Source Database:
Pump client      10gR1      10gR2      11gR1      11gR2      12cR1
    version   10.1.0.x   10.2.0.x   11.1.0.x   11.2.0.x   12.1.0.x
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
   10.1.0.x  supported  supported  supported  supported  supported
   10.2.0.x         no  supported  supported  supported  supported
   11.1.0.x         no         no  supported  supported  supported
   11.2.0.x         no         no         no  supported  supported
   12.1.0.x         no         no         no         no  supported
```

12c impdp can process all dump file versions:

"Import Data Pump can always read Export Data Pump dumpfile sets created by older versions of the database."

Comment: So isn't it like a limitation from Oracle? Other than that I agree with 100% of your answer.

Comment: Yes, this is a limitation from Oracle. If you have access to an 11.2 client you can do the expdp against the source db. You don't need remote access to the server itself. The client software can be downloaded here:
(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html)

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciate the help.

Comment: The last paragraph is false; I get UDI-00018 when using the 12.1.0.2.0 impdp to import 11.2.0.1.0 dump files.

Comment: I retract my previous comment. The reason I was getting UDI-00018 is because impdp from 12.1 was trying to import the 11.2 dump into the 11.2 database. If you have both databases installed on the same machine, one will use a different port number than the other.

Answer (score 1):

The data could be easily exported from 11g by using 12c expdp utility if you have a db link between 12c and 11g DBs (in this case, you make connection to 12c db). 
Here is a simple example:

```
expdp user/password@host/service schemas=sample_schema network_link=link_to_11g directory=tmp dumpfile=sample_schema.dmp logfile=blabla.log
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are exporting from Oracle 12c and importing to Oracle 11g. In order to do that you'll need the `VERSION` parameter ([Source](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_export_import_different_releases_of_oracle.htm)):

On your 12c instance (ignore the 11g references):

```
C:\Users\Steve>expdp hr/hr TABLES=hr.employees2 VERSION=10.2 DIRECTORY=data_pump_dir DUMPFILE=emp2.dmp LOGFILE=emp2.log

Export: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Sep 7 09:10:51 2010

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Starting "HR"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01":  hr/******** TABLES=hr.employees2 VERSION=10.2 DIRECTORY=data_pump_dir DUMPFILE=emp2.dmp LOGFILE=emp2.log

Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 64 KB

Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE

. . exported "HR"."EMPLOYEES2"                           16.12 KB     107 rows

Master table "HR"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************

Dump file set for HR.SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01 is:
  C:\APP\ORACLE\ADMIN\ORCL\DPDUMP\EMP2.DMP

Job "HR"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully completed at 09:11:01
```

Then on your 11g Instance (again, ignore the 10g references):

```
C:\Users\Steve>impdp hr/hr TABLES=hr.employees2 DIRECTORY=data_pump_dir DUMPFILE=emp2.dmp LOGFILE=emp2_imp.log

Import: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tuesday, 07 September, 2010 9:25:53

Copyright (c) 2003, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

Master table "HR"."SYS_IMPORT_TABLE_01" successfully loaded/unloaded

Starting "HR"."SYS_IMPORT_TABLE_01":  hr/******** TABLES=hr.employees2 DIRECTORY=data_pump_dir DUMPFILE=emp2.dmp LOGFILE=emp2_imp.log

Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA

. . imported "HR"."EMPLOYEES2"                           16.12 KB     107 rows

Job "HR"."SYS_IMPORT_TABLE_01" successfully completed at 09:26:05
```

Comment: No. I am exporting a schema from 11g for backup purposes. I used to do it from the server itself but now I do not have remote server access to the server. But I have a 12g database server (same network) with all accesses. Now I need to use 12g datapump utility to do a expdp of the 11g schema

Answer (score 0):

To import from a 11g to a 12c. As mentioned above, the network_link option also works, as long as both users have the privilege to export. If they are not available, I have used the dblink created in a 12c to do an insert-select and then I use the 12c expdp. But the best thing is to have an 11g client.

Network_link Usage Example

> expdp usr12c/pwdusr12c@12c directory = dpump_dir1
> network_link=dblinkname DUMPFILE = usr11g_table_name.dmp TABLES =
> table_name